# WordPress Side Navigation with Parent Heading and Child Sub Pages

Tags: wp-list-pages

I have the following navigational structure in WordPress:

```
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
  Page
     Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
```

On each Sub Page and Child Page, I want to display the following in the sidebar:

```
  Sub Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
        Child Page
```

The closest I've come to this is the following code from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-only-page-siblings?replies=19):

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );      
wp_list_pages( array(
       'title_li' => '',
       'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
       'depth' => '1' )
);
?>
</ul>
```

However, on Sub Pages it only shows a list of all Sub Pages (without Child Pages) and on Child Pages, it displays a list of Child Pages of that section but the parent Sub Page title is missing.

How do I modify to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the **`depth`** parameter to how many levels you want the walker to traverse.

From the docs **depth** parameter description.

> *Number of levels in the hierarchy of pages to include in the generated list. Accepts -1 (any depth), 0 (all pages), 1 (top-level pages only), and n (pages to the given n depth). Default 0.*

Let us say 2 as the depth level ,  it outputs both SubPages and it's first level children.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );      
    wp_list_pages( array(
           'title_li' => '',
           'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
           'depth' => '2' // Traverses SubPage and it's first level children
         )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @bravokeyl but that doesn't give me what I'm looking for. On Sub Pages it shows a list of ALL Sub Pages (with ALL Child Pages) and on Child Pages, it still displays a list of Child Pages of that section but the parent Sub Page title is still missing.

Comment: @TroyTempleman, are you sure for subpages , all subpages with all child pages are displayed ? childpages shouldn't be displayed. Are you getting correct `$current_page_parent` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Perhaps it has to do with my navigational structure? It's three levels deep. I do want child pages displayed, just not the ones from other Sub Pages (or their parent Sub Page). I only want Child Pages from the current Sub Page, and the exact same thing on Child Pages.